# How to show description on blueimp Gallery for Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, gallery

I am trying to read the documentation and figure out how to "initialize the Gallery with an onlide callback option" but failing at successfully implementing it. I would appreciate any help with this.

Here is my codepen link http://cdpn.io/lkFws

Here is the link to the documentation on this plugin https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out after pondering on the documentation for few more minutes. here is the finished result. Note where the `onslide: function(index,slide){…` is in the js.

Comment: Did you create a new codepen, but forget to link it here?  Or did you update your original one with the description text working?  I'm not seeing the description in the lightbox modal.

Comment: I am sorry, I have completely forgotten about this old project and don't know what to say to your question. I'm not seeing the description in the lightbox modal either. I'd have to, in my free time, go back and figure out how I solved it.